# iPhone - Convert CTFont to UIFont?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uifont, ctfont

I am trying to convert a CTFont to a UIFont without losing any of the styles and attributes such as:

- Font Name
- Font Size
- Font color
- Underlines
- Bold
- Italic
- etc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
CTFontRef ctFont = ...;
NSString *fontName = [(NSString *)CTFontCopyName(ctFont, kCTFontPostScriptNameKey) autorelease];
CGFloat fontSize = CTFontGetSize(ctFont);
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
```

Color and underline are not attributes of the font. Bold and italic are part of the font name.

Comment: This is wrong if your font doesn't appear in UIFont.familyNames presumably because it was loaded at runtime without GSFontAddFromFile.

Answer (score 0):

With ARC:

```
UIFont *uiFont = [UIFont fontWithName:(__bridge NSString *)CTFontCopyPostScriptName(ctFont) size:CTFontGetSize(ctFont)];
```