# UIFont API to simplify font style modification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uifont

I search an API to simplify the iphone font style modification (bold,italic,boldItalic etc) in an UILabel. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by `simplify`?

Comment: I mean for example instead of :
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" withSize:25];
do :
UIFont *font = [UIfont fontWithfamily:family style:Bold size:size];

Comment: There is no API to simplify that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do that with a UIFont using public methods.

There's a private method that does it, but of course you couldn't use that in an App Store app:

```
+(UIFont*)fontWithFamilyName:(NSString*)familyName traits:(GSFontTraitMask)traits size:(CGFloat)fontSize;
```

If you were using Core Text, you could create the font as a `CTFontRef`, then use `CTFontDescriptorCreateCopyWithAttributes()` with `kCTFontTraitsAttribute` set to `kCTFontBoldTrait` or `kCTFontItalicTrait` etc, which would get you a bold or italic version of the font you first created. Then I suppose you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714858/iphone-convert-ctfont-to-uifont) to convert it into a UIFont. It's a bit of a cumbersome solution though.

Comment: Thanks you for you help, i'm going to try this !